# What does cin do when there is an error

Tags: c++, error-handling, cin

```
#include<iostream>;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << "+" << b << "=" << a+b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when I enter `3 4` as input,the output will be `3+4=7`,well,it's strange;
But when I enter `a b`,the output is `0+0=0`(Why it is 0 and 0?);
The most confusing,`a 4`,it will be `0+0=0`(Why not '0+4=4'?????);
Then i write another prog.

```
#include<iostream>;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << a << "+" << b << "=" << a+b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i enter `a 4`,why  is  it still `0+0=0`?Shouldn't it be `0+4=4`?

Thanks to all the warm-hearted!!

I write prog3,to test what will happen when i don't write `int a=1;int b=2`;

```
2

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
    int a,b;
    cin >> a  ;
    cin >> b;
    cout<< a << "+"<< b <<"="<< a+b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When `a b`again,it outputs `0+-1218170892=-1218170892`(Why isn't `0+0=0`??)

Comment: the input is expected to be an integer, not a character. Entering "a", "3.141" or "whatever" simply isn't valid. If your input is "a", the program doesn't know that you've used "a" as a variable and that you want to use the default value instead.

Comment: It's obvious that it is C++11, because otherwise, the values would be 1 and 2, not 0's.

Comment: To answer your edit: You haven't removed a from the input. You need `cin.clear(); cin.ignore(1);`, so that the second extraction will succeed.

Comment: @Drise Can u help me about the prog3?

Comment: a and b are uninitialized. They have garbage values from the memory that was given to them. It's meaningless information. Always use int a = 0; to ensure you're going to get *usable* data.

Comment: @Drise But why zero is not written to value just as Prog1 and Prog2 do.I mean, what's the difference between garbage values and the `1` and `2` in Prog1 & Prog2.

Comment: You know, that's a very good question. One that I can't answer. I believe @james was trying to find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 3):

Like all `istreams`, `std::cin` has error bits. These bits are set when errors occur. For example, you can find the values of the error bits with functions like `good()`, `bad()`, `eof()`, etc. If you read bad input (`fail()` returns `true`), use `clear()` to clear the flags. You will also likely need an `ignore(1);` to remove the offending character.

See the `State functions` section for more information. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios

Comment: Thanks.But i'm sill wondering why the value of a and b both become 0

Comment: If you read bad input, `bad()` will still return false; it's `fail()` which will return true.  And the page you cite is misleadingly simplified, and simply wrong with regards to `good()` (which can return false even if no error has occurred).  Throw it out, and find something better.

Comment: You seem to be using C++11:  *If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. **(since C++11)***.

Comment: OK,now i kown it;Thanks again:)

Comment: @user1668903 If both become 0, it is an error in the implementation.  C++11 requires the first to become 0, and the second to be unchanged.  Earlier versions of the standard required both to be unchanged.

Comment: Why? It's going to try to finish the statement (continue extracting), even if the stream has failed. Or at least that's how I was always taught. Source?

Comment: @Drise A quote from the standard for this, please.  I'm looking at a very late draft (N3376), and that's not what it says.  `num_get` is required to set the value to 0 for certain types of failure, but the implementation shouldn't change the value if `num_get` isn't called (because of a preceding error).

Comment: I don't have a quote, unfortunately. But I have always been under the impression that if you write `cin >> a >> b;`, it won't simply lop off `>> b` because extraction into `a` failed. It doesn't make sense that it would. And as far as I knew, `cin >> a >> b;` is synonymous with `cin >> a; cin >> b;`, which would then guarantee that the extraction is done twice, and both values get set to 0.

Comment: Since `cin >> a >> b` is essentially equivalent to `( cin.operator>>(a) ).operator>>(b)`, I would think that `fail()` should be true after the failed extraction into `a`, and that the extraction to `b` would then not even be attempted. The single clause quoted above by @Drise is ambiguous on this particular case - but other sections might apply to clarify it... Of course that assumes that an extraction operation checks the state bits before attempting anything and aborts if `fail()` is true (or others...), but that could be a false assumption.

Comment: @twalberg Or not: The (1-7) versions of the operator behave as formatted input functions. That is, they construct a sentry object at the beginning that flushes the tie()'d buffers if needed, **checks for errors**, and extracts and discards all leading whitespace characters unless the ios_base::skipws flag was cleared. The input **is attempted only if** the sentry object returns **true**. Version 2 is `basic_istream& operator>>( int& value );`

Answer (score 3):

The value is set to zero on an error as per C++11: If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set.

On the 'a 4' example, both values are 0 because the buffer has not been flush/cleared, so the second cin read is still reading the error, and also receives a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

std::cin is an istream instance and thus it maintains its error state when it reads something invalid.

In order to "cure" it you must both clear its flag

```
std::cin.clear();
```

and flush its buffer.

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

What is more surprising though is that it doesn't return 1 + 2 = 3 when you input invalid characters, as I would expect a failing cin stream to have no side effects on what it is trying to update.

Comment: OP is using C++11: *If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. **(since C++11)***

Comment: Is this just the case with ints, or is it a general rule for user types that if streaming in fails, the object should revert to its default state? I always think streaming into an object is flawed logic. Factories create objects with data read from streams, objects don't get streamed into..

Comment: "*streaming into an object is flawed logic. Factories create objects with data read from streams, objects don't get streamed into*" - streaming with `operator<<` is necessarily into pre-existing objects (given the by-reference parameter), and although a factory creating a new object may fairly often be desirable, there are times when it wouldn't (e.g. when you want buffers and other resources the object already has re-used for the next value) and how would the "factory" create objects on the stack (highly desirable unless the objects are run-time polymorphic, need extended lifetime etc.)?

Comment: I tend to prefer classes to be non-intrusive and there is more than one way to serialise data. Of course having gained more experience with the library I do now know there is such a thing as a facet but it is complicated.

In any case I have found in recent years I am more into creating straightforward "struct" objects that contain all the data members public, then having a "class" wrap the struct by containing a private instance of it. You can then "stream" into the struct without having to make anything a friend, and keep the encapsulation the members of the instance are still inaccessible.